# Need to separate records with a QTY column into individual records where QTY is always 1

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have a dataset with 82147 obs and 36 variables and I need to find the top 200 levels of the "Description" column with the highest frequency, but there is a QTY column in the dataset so although I am finding the most frequent levels of "Description," I am not getting a true picture of what is the most frequently repeated items as each record also lists a QTY which is not 1.

```
Top20InvDesc <- names(sort(summary(as.factor(Inventory$Description)), 
                      decreasing=T)[1:20])

Top20InvDesc
```

I have tried this and continue to scour the internet on how to do this, but I also do not know how to properly ask this question so I am looking at a lot of similar stuff but nothing that is what I need.

```
Top20InvDesc <- names(sort(summary(as.factor(Inventory$Description)), 
                      decreasing=T)[1:20])

Top20InvDesc
```

and

```
library(dplyr)
Inventory %>% 
  group_by(Description) %>%
  top_n(5, Qty)
```

Say that a "syringe" is one of the levels in the "Description" column and it is the most repeated level, but each record has a QTY of 5. There is also a level of "gloves" in the "Description" column and it is the 5th most repeated level, but the QTY is 1000 for each. I know that the "gloves" should be the first item in the new dataframe I am trying to make, but I cannot figure out how to get my code to do this. The easiest way I can think of to solve my problem is to create a new dataframe where each item is listed as QTY 1 and only use the top 20 items.

What I am Getting

```
Description
<fctr>
ARMBOARD INTRAVENOUS NEONATAL 4X1.5IN FOAM SEMIFLEXIBLE DISPOSABLE LATEX FREE-BG/24EA

Qty
<int>
32
```

What I want to get and the Armboard will now be listed 32 times.

```
Description
<fctr>
ARMBOARD INTRAVENOUS NEONATAL 4X1.5IN FOAM SEMIFLEXIBLE DISPOSABLE LATEX FREE-BG/24EA

Qty
<int>
1
```

My laptop has 32 GB memory and a 180 Watt power supply so I was thinking I will need to deal with the linger processing time, but this will also make the data much easier to work with.

Comment: `library(dplyr); Inventory %>% 
  count(Description, wt = Qty) %>%
  top_n(20, n)` This should output the top 20 items in terms of total quantity. It would help to clearly define "highest frequency" if you don't mean either "most rows in the data" (in which case what's the relevance of QTY?) or "most total volume" (my answer).

Comment: `Inventory %>% group_by(Description) %>% summarise(n = sum(QTY)) %>% top_n()` I think.

Comment: Thank you so much @JonSpring , but I should have been more clear. This worked fine, but would you have the code to create a dataframe which uses only the records which contain these top 20 items so I can see their respective variables and however many records?

Comment: @Axeman , thank you so much as well, your code gave a similar result!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
details_from_top20 <- Inventory %>%
  group_by(Description) %>% 
  summarise(n = sum(QTY)) %>% 
  top_n(20) %>%
  left_join(Inventory)
```

For a reproducible example, we could use `mtcars` and get all the data for the cars which have the gear with highest total weight, in this case 3 gears. (It's a little contrived, but structurally the same problem.)

```
car_gears_with_top2_weights <- mtcars %>%
  group_by(gear) %>% 
  summarise(total_wt = sum(wt*1000)) %>% 
  top_n(1) %>%
  left_join(mtcars)

# A tibble: 15 x 12
    gear total_wt   mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  carb
   <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     3    58389  21.4     6  258    110  3.08  3.22  19.4     1     0     1
 2     3    58389  18.7     8  360    175  3.15  3.44  17.0     0     0     2
 3     3    58389  18.1     6  225    105  2.76  3.46  20.2     1     0     1
 4     3    58389  14.3     8  360    245  3.21  3.57  15.8     0     0     4
 5     3    58389  16.4     8  276.   180  3.07  4.07  17.4     0     0     3
 6     3    58389  17.3     8  276.   180  3.07  3.73  17.6     0     0     3
 7     3    58389  15.2     8  276.   180  3.07  3.78  18       0     0     3
 8     3    58389  10.4     8  472    205  2.93  5.25  18.0     0     0     4
 9     3    58389  10.4     8  460    215  3     5.42  17.8     0     0     4
10     3    58389  14.7     8  440    230  3.23  5.34  17.4     0     0     4
11     3    58389  21.5     4  120.    97  3.7   2.46  20.0     1     0     1
12     3    58389  15.5     8  318    150  2.76  3.52  16.9     0     0     2
13     3    58389  15.2     8  304    150  3.15  3.44  17.3     0     0     2
14     3    58389  13.3     8  350    245  3.73  3.84  15.4     0     0     4
15     3    58389  19.2     8  400    175  3.08  3.84  17.0     0     0     2
```

Comment: Thank you Jon! @JonSpring would you know how to get the items listed as individual Line items thus making each line item representing QTY 1 as opposed to QTY 40 or whatever each line item has for their QTY? The reason I wanted it done like this is it would make it easy to graph and get accurate numbers for totals.

Comment: `tidyr::uncount(QTY)` will make as many copies of a row as QTY.